# Как избавиться от обводки в IE 9 по краю всей страницы?

Tags: html, javascript, css

[Пример](http://stalker-bit.ucoz.com/home.html)

Comment: Такая же обводка у английской версии гугл

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В стандартном юкоз стиле есть вот это:

```
body { 
display: block;
margin: 8px; 
margin-top: 8px; 
margin-right: 8px; 
margin-bottom: 8px; 
margin-left: 8px; 
}
```

[image]

Попробуйте margin* поставить в "0".

Comment: ++http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#border-properties

Comment: Моя страница не имеет связи с юкозовскими стилями. Посмотрите код моей странице, подскажите что делать с обводкой? На русском гугле ее нет а на английской версии есть.

Comment: Код выше я выдрал с вашей страницы. Юкоз добавляет этот код автоматом. Нужно просто переопределить стили margin внутри кода страницы.

Comment: body {
margin: 0;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
overflow-y: scroll;
}  
Это часть кода стиля google.ru

Comment: но этот код,это не возможно вот мой код 
 
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
html, body {background-color: #000;}
a {padding:6px; text-decoration:none; color:#FFF;}
a:hover {border-bottom: 1px dotted white;}
</style>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Сталкер портал</title>
</head>

<body>
<p><a href="/">На главную</a><a href="/">Новости</a><a href="/">Файлы</a></p>
</body>
</html>

Comment: и почему тогда у гугла есть обводка?

Comment: Если в хроме нажать ctrl+shift+c, можно увидеть полностью код страницы, и не только. И ещё border none поставьте.